# Pelican can't find custom static files

Tags: pelican

When I load my pelican site, no custom style appears (I double-checked by inspecting), and the icon doesn't display either.

The following error messages show when I run `make serve` or `make serve-global`:

```
           WARNING  Unable to find `/static/custom.css` or variations:                                                                                                       log.py:91
                    /static/custom.css.html                                                                                                                                           
                    /static/custom.css/index.html                                                                                                                                     
                    /static/custom.css                                                                                                                                                
           WARNING  Unable to find `/favicon.ico` or variations:                                                                                                             log.py:91
                    /favicon.ico.html                                                                                                                                                 
                    /favicon.ico/index.html                                                                                                                                           
                    /favicon.ico
```

I made sure that the icon and the CSS file are present in the `content` directory. I have tried moving them to the root directory of the website, which didn't help.

I have also tried moving them to the `output` directory, which was a successful workaround. It doesn't really solve the problem though, since that directory should be automatically generated (and it probably wouldn't help at all if I tried to publish the site).

If it matters, I use the [`pelican-twitchy`](https://github.com/ingwinlu/pelican-twitchy/) theme and have set `CUSTOM_CSS = 'static/custom.css'` in the `pelicanconf.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

The path where the custom CSS file is, must be in the `STATIC_PATHS` array in the `pelicanconf.py` file. That way, anything in that directory will be copied to the output directory.

Same applies to `favicon.ico`.

Therefore, the `STATIC_PATHS` array has to contain at least `'static'` and `'favicon.ico'`.